# Curtain.js + Jquery + HTML5 - Header & Controls disappear after 2nd slide

Tags: jquery, html, header, safari

Can anyone help me with my first HTML5 and Jquery website?

I'm using this curtain.js that allows me to have layered fixed slides that reveal themselves one slide at a time with a curtain like effect.

I have a fixed header and controls that are suppose to stay in same position and visible the entire index page viewing and scrolling.

It works correctly with FireFox on desktop, Chrome on desktop, and safari on iPhone5.  Weird thing is that the header and controls disappear after the second slide with Safari 6.0.2 on my desktop.

Its really bugging me, I can't figure out why. Please help.

Thanks in advance, hopefully someone can be my lifesaver!

http://www.taggrafx.com/HarrisHousing/index.html

Comment: have you figured out how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the -webkit-transform to the fixed element solved the issue for me.

```
.fixed_element {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   position: fixed;
   ....
}
```

Comment: ah, the modern `hasLayout`.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to acknowledge your solution, I couldn't figure out how to give you the thumbs up until now. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to the .curtains class